# Spring-security creates malformed ldap-query

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to get a Single-signon solution working, which has previously worked with Novell eDirectory as an LDAP-provider. Now, I am trying to get it to work with OpenLDAP. In the signon-process, one of the steps is retrieving the actual user from the LDAP. This is done by Spring-security, but it seems to have a bug.

For getting the user, `LdapUserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername` is called. This uses a predefined `LdapUserSearch` to find a user with the given username. In my case, the configuration looks something like this:

```
base:ou=something,ou=somethingElse,dc=oh,dc=my,dc=god
filter:cn={0}
```

where `{0}` is replaced with the actual username. So far this works, and the user is retrieved, in the form of userdata returned by `FilterBasedLdapUserSearch#searchForUser`. But, the userdata does not separate between dn and base, so it has:

```
base:  (empty)
dn:cn=someUsername,ou=something,ou=somethingElse,dc=oh,dc=my,dc=god
```

This userdata-object is in turn used to retrieve the authorities for the user, so it the tries to do another search with the base above, and the dn as filter. But, this query fails, since OpenLDAP does not allow any queries with an empty string as base.

I have tried with 3.1.3.RELEASE, 3.1.7.RELEASE and 3.2.7.RELEASE, all have the same issue.

Is this a bug in spring-security? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it, by moving away from the "template" way of defining the ldap user service:

Before:

```
  <sec:ldap-user-service id="ldapUserDetailsService"
                     server-ref="contextSource"
                     user-search-filter="${my.ldap.filter}"
                     user-search-base="${my.ldap.base}"
                     user-context-mapper-ref="myUserDetailsContextMapper"/>
```

After:

```
  <bean id="userSearch"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${my.ldap.base}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${my.ldap.filter}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
      <constructor-arg value="${my.ldap.usersearch.base}"/>
      <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="${my.group.filter}" />
      <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="${my.group.attribute}" />
    <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="ldapUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="userSearch"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
  </bean>
```

Don't ask me how or why this works..